# Sharing 'Document' sobject among different user?

Tags: rest-api, sharing, document

Say, there are two users - A and B. 
One document - X

X is owned by A but shared with B.

The REST Access is granted with user B.

If X was modified by A, would invoking 'updated' API from B's context - return X's id ?

What is the scope of uniqueness of a particular document ID ? Are they unique within an instance ? Or is it per user ?

Comment: Document, Content, or Attachment?

Answer (score 2):

ID values are unique across the entire server, and can be accessed by any user within the same organization as the one that created the ID, assuming they have permission. In other words, `getUpdated()` will return the same ID for X for all users that can see X.